# Printing SQL select result set directly onto HTML webpage?

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, resultset

How can I rewrite my code below to print the results directly on my webpage instead of on the console?

```
 public static void doSQL() {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:msql://...";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Lname FROM Customers WHERE Snum = 2001");
            while ( rs.next() ) {

                // I want to print the ResultSet directly on my HTML page, how may I go about doing that?
                String lastName = rs.getString("Lname");
                System.out.println(lastName);
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well which web technologies are you using?  If you were using a JSP,  you could print a table to the page.

Comment: No JSPs, just plain servlet.

Comment: like if i just print the Result Set with a Print Writer the outcome is just an Object name with a bunch of random letters and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to obtain a writer from the servlet response and then write the HTML content you want.  I made a slight refactor of your `doSQL()` method to accept a `PrintWriter` as a parameter.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    doSQL(pw);
}

public static void doSQL(PrintWriter pw) {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:msql://...";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Lname FROM Customers WHERE Snum = 2001");
        pw.println("<html><table>");
        while (rs.next()) {
            // you only select one field, but you can easily adapt
            // this code to have more fields (i.e. table columns)
            String lastName = rs.getString("Lname");
            pw.println("<tr><td>" + lastname + "</td></tr>");
        }
        pw.println("</table></html>");
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return resultset.

```
public static ResultSet doSQL() {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:msql://...";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Lname FROM Customers WHERE Snum = 2001");

            conn.close();
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null
    }
```

in your servlet, get the doSQL();

```
ResultSet rs = MyStaticFile.doSQL();
int rowCount = 0;

 out.println("<P ALIGN='center'><TABLE BORDER=1>");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 // table header
 out.println("<TR>");
 for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
   out.println("<TH>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1) + "</TH>");
   }
 out.println("</TR>");
 // the data
 while (rs.next()) {
  rowCount++;
  out.println("<TR>");
  for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString(i + 1) + "</TD>");
    }
  out.println("</TR>");
  }
 out.println("</TABLE></P>");
```

This is not a full example and not fully test yet. This reference will get you the idea how to do it. Btw, dont use static for DB operation. You can use for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example with reference to your code of servlet response as html for html request with GET method, similarly you can write for POST method. Add below code in servlet.

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response) throws IOException { 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(  ); 
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");

out.println("<title> Any Title </title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<H1>Last Name from a Servlet</H1></br>"); 
try {
        String url = "jdbc:msql://...";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","password");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Lname FROM Customers WHERE Snum = 2001");
        while ( rs.next() ) {

            // I want to print the ResultSet directly on my HTML page, how may I go about doing that?
            String lastName = rs.getString("Lname");
            out.println("<H1>"+ lastName +"</H1></br>");
            System.out.println(lastName);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");

      out.close();

}
```